# jQuery: absolute pathname before hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hashchange

I'm currently experiencing some conflict between a hashchange function I have set up and jQuery mobile (used for sliding page transitions).
To demonstrate here's an isolated demo on my server: http://nealfletcher.co.uk/transition/ 
Click on `transition click` which slides the relevant page in, as it should and appends the url accordingly: `/transition/news`. 
This is where the problem lies, click on `news hash click` and this will fire my hashchange function and load in the relevant div, BUT instead of the url being like so: `/transition/news/#news-01` the url is being rendered like so `/transition/#news-01` which causes problems when navigating to the url. 

Is there anyway to force the `/news/` to be added before the hash, so I get `/transition/news/#news-01` instead of `/transition/#news-01`?
The relevant jQuery is below, is it at all possible to append `/news/` before the hash?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).hashchange(function () {
        var hash = location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            var element = $('.click-block[data-hook="' + hash.substring(1) + '"]');
            if (element) showDetail(element);
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).hashchange();

        var $container = $('#main-grid, #news-grid');

        $(function () {
            $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.grid-block, .grid-break, .hidden',
                    animationEngine: 'best-available',
                    filter: '*:not(.hidden), .grid-block',
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: 8,
                        gutterWidth: 25
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        $(".click-block").click(function () {
            document.location.hash = $(this).attr('data-hook');
        });
    });


    function showDetail(element) {

        var newHeight = $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).height();
        $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).removeClass('hidden').addClass('grid-break').delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
        newHeight = (Math.floor((newHeight + 10) / 230) + 1) * 230 - 10;
        $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).css('height', newHeight);

        element.children('.up-arrow').fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).offset().top - 90
            }, "slow");
        }, 1500);
        $('#main-grid').isotope();
        $('#news-grid').isotope();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the section in your data-hook attribute. So for your news links they will be prefixed by news/ like so `data-hook="news/news-01"`

Now, I would reccomend you to consider using something like http://backbonejs.org/#Router for what you'r doing. Or atleast take a look at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: this changes the url like so though `/news/news-01` and doesn't include the hash before `news-01` like it should, and thus the function doesn't work to show the `#post-news-01` div.

Comment: Why do you need the hash? Id suggest to read up on why the hashchange event from HTML4 is considered deprecated. Why not use history.js?

Comment: I probably won't next time round as it's becoming too problematic, but for now I just need a temporary solution to this problem until I can find something more permanent, which will probably be history.js. For now though, is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: You can just add whatever you need into your data-hook, so for example data-hook="news/#news-01", and then just retrieve the string after your # and load that. But if you want to keep correct history, possibility to bookmark the urls etc. you have a lot of extra work to do. History.js is very easy to implement. :)